# Geocoder get location: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Tags: android, android-asynctask, geolocation, android-location

I want to get the `city name` from the `location` object. I am doing that in an `async task`in the main activity using `android.location.GeoCoder`.

This is how I am doing it:

```
public void getCityName(final Location location,
            final OnGeocoderFinishedListener listener) {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Integer, List<Address>>() {
            @Override
            protected List<Address> doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.ENGLISH);
                List<Address> results = null;
                try {
                    results = coder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(),
                            location.getLongitude(), 1);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // nothing
                }
                return results;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(List<Address> results) {
                if (results != null && listener != null) {
                    listener.onFinished(results);
                }
            }
        }.execute();
    }

    public abstract class OnGeocoderFinishedListener {
        public abstract void onFinished(List<Address> results);
    }
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
05-23 12:30:08.395: E/AndroidRuntime(24099): FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
05-23 12:30:08.395: E/AndroidRuntime(24099): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
05-23 12:30:08.395: E/AndroidRuntime(24099):    at orient.tvguide.main.MainActivity.getCityName(MainActivity.java:573)
05-23 12:30:08.395: E/AndroidRuntime(24099):    at orient.tvguide.main.MainActivity$1.gotLocation(MainActivity.java:289)
05-23 12:30:08.395: E/AndroidRuntime(24099):    at orient.tvguide.location.MyLocation$GetLastLocation.run(MyLocation.java:116)
05-23 12:30:08.395: E/AndroidRuntime(24099):    at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
05-23 12:30:08.395: E/AndroidRuntime(24099): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
05-23 12:30:08.395: E/AndroidRuntime(24099):    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
05-23 12:30:08.395: E/AndroidRuntime(24099):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.<init>(AsyncTask.java:607)
05-23 12:30:08.395: E/AndroidRuntime(24099):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.<init>(AsyncTask.java:607)
05-23 12:30:08.395: E/AndroidRuntime(24099):    at android.os.AsyncTask.<clinit>(AsyncTask.java:190)
05-23 12:30:08.395: E/AndroidRuntime(24099):    ... 4 more
```

I have also tried to run the `async` on the `runOnUiThread`, but still the issue persists.

```
public void getCityName(final Location location,
            final OnGeocoderFinishedListener listener) {

        this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                new AsyncTask<Void, Integer, List<Address>>() {
                    @Override
                    protected List<Address> doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                        Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.ENGLISH);
                        List<Address> results = null;
                        try {
                            results = coder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(),
                                    location.getLongitude(), 1);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // nothing
                        }
                        return results;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(List<Address> results) {
                        if (results != null && listener != null) {
                            listener.onFinished(results);
                        }
                    }
                }.execute();
            }
        });
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here??

Comment: your async task as a whole is behaving like its on the main ui thread try making two asynctask instead of runonuithread

Answer (score 0):

Add this piece of code inside `onBackground()` before `Geocoder coder = new Geocoder();`

```
try {
    Looper.prepare();
} catch (Exception e) {
    //Allready called
}
```

And tell me your results :)

Comment: then put outside onBackGround() this   'Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.ENGLISH);'

Comment: Is this somehow related to the device settings?

Comment: @faizanjehangir updating ui from doinbsckground??

Comment: @Raghunandan no, the `doinbackground` gets the address feed from the location obj params.. device's gps satellite and google locations services are both turned on..

Comment: @faizanjehangir generally this happens when you update ui from a background thread